# Value not binding to viewModel using controller as & ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to create radio buttons for my form.  The issue I am having is the value is not binding to the viewModel when an item is checked.

The name of my 'controller as' is 'request'.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-repeat="type in request.serviceTypes">
     <div class="form-wrapper">
          <input type="radio" ng-checked="type.isChecked" class="form-control" name="serviceType" ng-value="{{type.name}}" ng-model="request.formData.serviceType">
          <label for="serviceType" required class="check" ng-click="request.toggleServiceType(type.id)">{{type.name}}</label>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  For the record I have no problem binding to request.formData when using input type of text, this issue only occurs with radio's.

The toggle service function code is below

```
vm.toggleServiceType = function(id){
        angular.forEach(vm.serviceTypes, function(serviceType, key){
            if(serviceType.id === id){
                serviceType.isChecked = true;
            }else{
                serviceType.isChecked = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

I've added a plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/g2juiZZqFihfcduiOH9n?p=preview

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @UtkuApaydin I've updated the question with a link to the plunkr

Comment: @cezar because that is technically not the proper way to do controllers anymore, especially if you are looking to migrate to Angular 2.0.  You especially should not be using $scope anymore.  Please look at Jon Papa's style guide as this is what the Angular team will be assuming everyone is following

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out the problem.  Apparently for radio buttons with angularJS it does not use the ng-checked.  It actually looks to see what the value of the model is.

What I did was modified the function to

```
request.toggleServiceType = function(name){
    request.formData.serviceType = name;
};
```

The updated plunkr can be viewed here http://plnkr.co/edit/F5S5Jz7LAoBi40Zzjmx7?p=preview